# ADB RSA key popup not showing on Nook Tablet with official CyanogenMod 10.1 Nightlies

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, 4.2-jelly-bean, android-sdk

I have a B&N Nook Tablet (my only Android device) with CyanogenMod 10.1 official Nightlies installed on it. I am trying to use ADB, I tapped on build number, opened dev options, and enabled USB debugging. When I run adb on my Ubuntu box w/ GNOME, all it does is says my device is offline and on the device, it doesn't give me the RSA popup. I am using ADB 1.0.31, which I got by installing the android-tools-adb package. I have also tried the same procedure with the ADB included in the SDK, and included with the SDK in the ADT Bundle and the new Android Studio. How do I make ADB work?

Comment: Could you please tell me the output of "ls -la ~/.android"